# Is there a problem about my method or is it me?

Tags: python, list

```
def thing():
    _list = [1,1,5,6,8,3,4,6,10,23,5,12,67,3,25,2,6,5,4,3,2,1]
    _list1 = [str(i) for i<=5 in _list]
    return " ".join(_list1)

print(thing())
```

Hello! The problem i am facing, I am trying to print put in a _list1 only integers elements that are lower than 5, I put all the elements in _list. Thank you!

Comment: `[str(i) for i in _list if i<=5]` -- the condition goes in an `if` clause...

Comment: Heeey, thank you so much, yes, It did help me! I appreciate it, thank you again

Comment: Note that using `<=` will also print 5. If you only want number less than five use `<`

Comment: Yes, that what i knew, i wanted the number 5 and everything less than that, so it reselves perfectly my problem, thank ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def thing():
    _list = [1,1,5,6,8,3,4,6,10,23,5,12,67,3,25,2,6,5,4,3,2,1]
    _list1 = [str(i) for i in _list if i <= 5]
    return " ".join(_list1)

print(thing())
```

Comment: Instead of answering, please vote to close as duplicate.